# É realmente necessário definir constraints no banco de dados?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

O Ruby on Rails parece ter sido pensado considerando que não é necessário definir *constraints* (como *Foreign Keys*) no banco de dados, bastando definí-los via aplicação.

Normalmente a única *constraint* que se cria nesse caso é a chave primária da coluna `id`, fora isto apenas índices (não obrigatoriamente como únicos) por questões de desempenho. Também não costumo usar `NOT NULL`, por exemplo.

De uma maneira geral isto facilita o desenvolvimento, especialmente no versionamento do Banco de Dados.

Devo me preocupar com riscos de integridade e afins ao se trabalhar desta forma (deixando tudo a cargo da aplicação)?

Comment: Isso facilita pra quem desenvolve em Ruby, e quando você desenvolve uma única aplicação. Pode parecer a última coca-cola do deserto agora, mas se algum dia outra aplicação construída em outra plataforma (ou mesmo em Ruby, sem reaproveitar a lógica atual) tiver que realizar operações de negócio na mesma base de dados, você só não vai chamar a mãe do sr. David Heinemeier Hansson de santa.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Em um servidor de produção, eu não confiaria somente na aplicação para garantir a integridade dos dados. A função de chaves estrangeiras é exatamente de garantir a relação entre as tabelas do Banco.

Supondo que um bug no relacionamento de dois models da aplicação seja percebido somente depois de algum tempo no servidor de produção, o tempo para a correção a nível de banco será muito maior do que o tempo de implementar corretamente as relações de chaves.

Atualmente desenvolvo em uma equipe pequena, onde a confiabilidade da informação é mais importante que a aplicação em si. Logo a criação das chave estrangeiras, definir os campos como `NOT NULL` e uma boa normalização no banco é para nós o primeiro passo.

Utilizamos o *Laravel* aqui, um framework em PHP que utiliza um *ORM* bem parecido com o *Active Record* do Rails. A definição de um banco bem estruturado nos ajuda a perceber erros de relação na aplicação logo no início, evitando que vários bugs entrem em produção.

Answer (score 10):

Não é necessário utilizá-las. Mas se você deve, é uma questão que depende de cada cenário.

O papel das constraints é garantir a integridade dos dados no banco. A decisão portanto de utilizá-las ou não, depende de como os dados são gerados. Se você pode garantir que apenas o seu aplicativo, devidamente homologado, cria, altera, atualiza e exclua registros, então, você pode dispensar as constraints. Mas se não for o caso, é aconselhável não fazer.

Já trabalhei em projetos em que as constraints não foram criadas nos bancos de produção, mas apenas nos de desenvolvimento, para apontar o erro do programador e auxiliar na homologação.

De qualquer forma, mesmo que opte por não utilizá-las, lembre-se que em muitos SGDBs as chave estrangeiras geram ou representam índices, e que neste caso, estes devem ser gerados explicitamente para evitar degradação nas operações SQL.

Comment: Regras na aplicação não garantem integridade dos dados. O Rails não garante (ver minha resposta). Para a aplicação conseguir isso sem uso de constraints seria necessário uso pesado de LOCKs na aplicação, que é complexo de se fazer e degrada a performance. A forma mais simples e garantida de manter a integridade é com uso de constraints no banco.

Comment: Não sei o que você chamou "Regras na aplicação". Deduzo que se refira à utilização de um recurso pré-existente em um nível de abstração mais elevado que não lhe permita, por ele, garantir a integridade. Mas independente da plataforma, linguagem ou framework, o programador sempre terá o poder de dispensar a abstração e assumir para si o controle sobre os algoritmos das operações CRUD e, portanto, pode implementar em nível de aplicativo a integridade dos dados. Sobre ser a forma mais simples; enfatizo o que eu disse: "se você deve (usar), é uma questão que depende de cada cenário".

Answer (score 9):

Como as respostas já disseram, depende do cenário em que você se encontra e dos requisitos da aplicação.

Mas algo que eu gostaria de acrescentar é que, nos casos onde não é necessário ter dados bem estruturados e bem definidos no banco de dados, talvez um SGBD relacional não seja a melhor resposta.

Aplicações de uso específico (por exemplo, que processam dados desestruturados do tipo usado em *Big Data*), ou com tempo de vida útil curto (não se prevê um uso prolongado do sistema pelos usuários) e alguns outros casos caem bem com NoSQL.

Enfim, ao usar um BD relacional sem aproveitar o que ele tem a oferecer você acaba por subaproveitar suas funcionalidades e ficar sem os benefícios que poderia obter.

Comment: concordo com tudo o que disse em relação a alternativa NoSQL; mas gostaria de enfatizar que a escolha pelo não uso de constraints não significa que não haja estruturação relacional. A estrutura relacional pode ser indispensável mesmo que constraints não sejam necessárias.

Comment: @Geziel Sim, concordo. O ponto é que se você faz todo o controle dos relacionamentos "manualmente" na aplicação, já não precisa de um banco de dados relacional.

Comment: Discordo. Relacionamento de dados é uma coisa e constraint é outra. Constraint é apenas um recurso dos SGDBs de obrigarem a integridade desses relacionamentos, mas, mesmo que você não utilize este recurso, ainda assim pode fazer uso da estrutura relacional. Você ainda pode fazer uso de todo o poder da SQL, que nos NoSQL é inexistente ou restrito. Você pode fazer Joins entre tabelas, Subconsultas, restrições where, etc. Em um cenário de alta performance, faz bastante sentido desativar as  constraints para otimização de resultados, por que o SGDB não precisa realizar checagens nas operações SQL.

Comment: @Geziel Em cenário de alta performance é justamente quando o NoSQL brilha. Quanto aos joins tudo bem, mas JOIN nenhum faz verificação de constraints, elas são usadas quando há manipulação dos dados. Não entendi bem seus argumentos, a não pela facilidade em usar Join.

Comment: Não argumentei isso. O que argumentei foi que mesmo não utilizando constraints, você pode usar recursos como Join por exemplo, e, portanto, há uma diferença entre constraint e relacionamento de dados.

Comment: @Geziel Certo, entendido.

Comment: Acho que entendi melhor o que você questionou. As checagens a que me referi são as realizadas pelos SGDBs nas operações de UPDATE, INSERT e DELETE.

Answer (score 4):

O Rails somente não garante integridade dos dados. Em especial, a validação de `uniqueness` não garante que não sejam criados registros duplicados em caso de acessos concorrentes. O próprio Rails Guides menciona isto em http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness.

Este [artigo](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations), em inglês, explica mais como isto pode ocorrer.

Além disso, eu sempre uso `NOT NULL` no banco de dados além da validação de `presence`. Não vejo motivo algum p/ não usar.

Geralmente eu não uso chaves estrangeiras, mas se você realmente se preocupa com integridade de dados, sugiro usar também.