# Regras de Negócio no Banco de Dados - quais as vantagens e desvantagens?

Tags: banco-de-dados, arquitetura-de-software, regra-de-negócio

Talvez eu me integre a uma equipe para desenvolver um novo projeto. O líder já tomou algumas decisões. Entre elas, que "**as regras de negócio estarão no banco de dados**". Em "*procedures*"  e "*views*", "*triggers*", *etc*.

Ao tomar conhecimento disto, minha primeira reação foi negativa - estou acostumado com regras de negócio na camada de aplicação, e não me parece uma boa ideia que fiquem no banco de dados.

Porém, o fato é que eu realmente não sei. Tampouco tenho experiência com essa arquitetura. Por isso, pergunto: Quais as vantagens? Quais as desvantagens? É uma boa prática? É uma má ideia?

Comment: Outro usuário fez hoje mesmo uma pergunta relacionada que talvez lhe seja interessante: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15702/e-realmente-necessario-definir-constraints-no-banco-de-dados#comment28468_15702

Comment: Acho que isso depende muito do que é para fazer, pode ser ou não vantajoso... Acho que fica um bocado na opinião e sensibilidade de cada um.

Comment: "Os dados pertencem à Organização, não à Aplicação." É bom ter isso em mente, além de todas as vantagens e desvantagens apontadas nas respostas. Se a empresa quiser fazer uso desses dados de uma forma **diferente** daquela que foi concebida (ex.: data mining, integração com sistemas externos, etc), o sistema será ou não um empecílio para isso? Se a resposta for "sim", temos um *lock-in* em potencial - o que é "bom" pros desenvolvedores mas ruim para o cliente.

Comment: Excelentes respostas propiciadas aqui abaixo! Será interessante, se de fato se integrar à equipe, publicar um feedback aqui da situação real (em termos conceituais em cima do que foi respondido, nada que fira a empresa, claro).

Comment: @mgibsonbr editei a resposta p/ refletir o que você disse. Eu não acredito que existam muitos casos em que você esteja completamente livre do *lock-in*. Quando você escolhe um modelo, você se prende a ele e nunca é fácil sair dele. Claro que se você é dono do modelo, é um pouco mais fácil, mas não acho que faça muita diferença na prática estar no DB ou não, a propriedade sim. Na teoria o Windows tem desvantagens, e tem mesmo. Na prática as empresas não ligam para isso e se preocupam com coisas mais palpáveis. Falta espaço p/ explicar melhor :) Boa sugestão do brasofilo.

Comment: O tratamento de grande volume de dados por uma Stored Procedure pode ser mais perfomático do que resgatar estes dados através da rede para processá-los no aplicativo, simplesmente porque a rotina que processa está mais próxima dos dados.

Não há **nenhuma** outra vantagem. Todas as vantagens citadas por Cigano e bigown podem ser usufruidas também ao programar a regra de negócio no aplicativo. E mesmo esta que eu citei é bastante questionável pois há muitos modelos de arquitetura para resolver problemas de performance sem precisar implementar a regra de negócio no SGBD.

Answer (score 55):

Vou tentar focar esta resposta no tocante a bancos de dados relacionais, que são os que tenho mais experiência e que devem abranger melhor o escopo da pergunta.

## Vantagens

- A segurança e a consistência dos dados são maiores;
- O permissionamento é feito a nível de dados, possibilitando a outros sistemas acessar diretamente a base, o que é bastante positivo em termos de desempenho;
- Como tabelas não são acessadas diretamente em termos de escrita (apenas em termos de leitura, quando isso acontece), a higienização de dados pode ser mais eficiente;
- *Defaults*, *Checks* e *Rules* evitam ausência de dados, definindo dados padrão e evitando inserção ou atualização de informações fora do escopo do negócio;
- Corretamente normalizado, é muito mais rápido em termos de leitura que qualquer ORM de qualquer linguagem de programação, pois não há a construção da consulta nem a transliteração dinâmica dos resultados.

## Desvantagens

- Mudanças são onerosas: quando é preciso modificar o esquema de alguma tabela ou chave, todos os objetos impactados precisam ser mudados manualmente;
- Demanda cuidado extra quanto a *tuning* e desempenho, pois *triggers* afetam a performance das leituras e escritas;
- Pode causar deadlocks e outros problemas específicos de bancos de dados, como geração anormal de informações por *triggers*;
- Sendo exageradamente programado, o comportamento do sistema pode se tornar obscuro, visto que alguns programadores e analistas usam indiscriminadamente artefatos como *Procedures* e *Triggers* para realizar programação pesada. Por exemplo, já vi um sistema que executava um cálculo inteiro de Folha de Pagamento chamando *Procedures* em cadeia. Funcionava bem e rápido, mas a implementação de um algoritmo dessa complexidade inteiramente em banco de dados é preocupante e bastante difícil de conferir;
- Pode se tornar um gargalo, se a tecnologia não suportar distribuição de carga. O caching fica inteiro no servidor de banco de dados;
- Não funciona bem com um número simultâneo de conexões muito grande (na casa dos milhares ou até dos milhões, por exemplo); Há bloqueio de E/S.

## É uma má prática?

Não. O conjunto de recursos que possui hoje um banco de dados foi inventado em uma época em que sistemas eram como cascas: apenas interfaces de acesso organizadas aos dados de um banco de dados. Um bom exemplo são as linguagens [MUMPS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS), [Cobol](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL), [Natural](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATURAL) e [SQLWindows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gupta_Technologies), em que basicamente quase todas as regras de manipulação massiva de dados eram feitas diretamente na base.

Entretanto, é preciso saber que esta é uma abordagem antiga e conservadora, portanto, pouco focada em produtividade. A manutenção e depuração é muito mais complexa do que numa camada de aplicação de um sistema moderno. Pode se tornar uma má prática se extrapolar o propósito do banco de dados, que é armazenar e manter responsavelmente as informações.

Answer (score 47):

## Vantagens

- Fica tudo em um único local. Fica mais fácil manter.
- **Pode** haver ganhos de performance. O softwares são otimizados para isso.
- Serve diversas aplicações usando diversas tecnologias e linguagens sem problemas. Permite até o acesso direto.
- Facilita o desenvolvimentos das aplicações por não precisar lidar com essa lógica.
- Permite um controle de acesso mais efetivo e granular ao banco.

Banco de dados é ótimo em armazenar e recuperar informações de diversas formas. Quando você quer fazer muito mais que isso, está usando a ferramenta errada. **Banco de dados é um mecanismo**, e ele é ótimo nisso. Ele não funciona muito bem tentando fornecer abstrações. Quando o mecanismo é mais importante, você faz nele.

Existe aplicação para tudo. Quando o banco de dados é mais importante que a aplicação, é possível fazer a lógica funcionar melhor dentro do DB. Um Data Warehouse, por exemplo se beneficia disto. Se o banco de dados define bem a solução e as aplicações rodando em cima dele são apenas satélites. Se, de certa forma, o banco de dados se torna a aplicação, faz sentido usar mais recursos dele.

Regras de negócios e regras de dados são coisas diferentes. **Regras de dados** cabem bem dentro do banco de dados, sempre.

Eu sei de outros itens que parecem vantagens, mas que há uma solução tão boa ou melhor colocando a lógica na aplicação. Só precisa entender como. Não vou colocar como vantagem coisas que só são vantagens se for feito do jeito certo e quando fizer do jeito certo na camada da aplicação, lá também é vantajoso. Por exemplo, se você souber o que está fazendo no DB ou na aplicação, os dados podem ficar consistentes. Se não souber, você vai ter problemas fazendo em qualquer um deles. Por isso que usar aquilo que você (ou sua equipe) sabe o que está fazendo é mais importante que a maneira de fazer. A resposta do Cigano Morrison Mendez mostra isso. A primeira vantagem que ele cita só é real se não acontecerem outros problemas, especialmente, mas não só, os citados por ele no primeiro e terceiro item das desvantagens.

## Desvantagens

- Praticamente exige um DBA para otimizar o banco de dados.
- Os desenvolvedores precisarão conhecer bem a linguagem do banco de dados. É raro encontrar profissionais com conhecimento e experiência além do trivial. É fácil achar quem ache que tem ambos.
- SQL, mesmo amplificada, não é muito expressiva. Costuma ser menos produtivo programar em qualquer variação disponível. Os códigos são bem feios e desorganizados.
- Programadores não entendem como fazer interfaces do banco de dados para aplicações adequadamente.
- O banco de dados recebem uma carga extra de trabalho que pode precipitar a necessidade de escalonamento. E é mais difícil escalar o DB que a aplicação.
- Você fica preso ao fornecedor de banco de dados ou tem trabalho para replicar a lógica para outros fornecedores, perdendo o primeiro item de vantagem.
- As aplicações ficam dependentes do banco de dados para conseguir fazer diversas manutenções.
- É ilusão achar que dá para colocar toda lógica no DB, então na prática acaba ficando com uma solução híbrida.
- Versionamento é bem mais complicado.
- Testes são mais complicados.
- Depuração é mais complicada.
- Documentação não é tão simples.
- Manter sincronismo do desenvolvimento entre a equipe é complicado.
- Não existem ferramentas tão boas para lidar com código em DB.
- Dificulta o reuso de código. Cria acoplamento excessivo.
- Uma alteração em um campo pode gerar uma quantidade enorme de alterações em cascata em outras partes do banco.
- Os programadores odeiam isso (opinião, ok, mas isso deve ser considerado).

Existem diversas formas de colocar a lógica na aplicação. Usar um ORM é apenas uma delas. O uso do ORM muitas vezes acaba sendo justificativa para colocar a lógica no DB, afinal é comum os ORMs serem complexos e inflexíveis.

Uma aplicação pode fazer a maior parte da lógica de negócios e deixar para o banco o que ele pode fazer melhor que a aplicação. Cuidado com a otimização prematura. Em banco de dados isso pode produzir resultados contrários mais facilmente. Se escolher colocar as regras de negócio somente como otimização pode estar criando mais uma desvantagem.

Se uma aplicação apenas usa o banco de dados como um mecanismo para armazenar dados e é ela é que é importante na solução, é claro que colocar mais do que é necessário no DB é ruim.

## Minha experiência

Particularmente eu costumo usar a lógica na aplicação, isto me serve bem, sai mais barato pra mim. Eu trabalho com softwares que são produtos. Então:

- Eu preciso ter mais controle sobre a aplicação.
- Eu preciso suportar fornecedores de banco de dados diversos.
- Eu sei que minha aplicação será a única a acessar o DB. Eu forneço uma API em um servidor de aplicação para outras aplicações acessarem o DB indiretamente.
- Eu preciso me livrar de todas as desvantagens que isso traz mais do que as vantagens que ela fornece.
- Toda a aplicação, incluindo a modelagem do banco de dados, é minha e não do cliente, só os dados são dele.
- Existe uma cultura estabelecida. Isso é importante para tomar decisões. Não é só o técnico que conta. Melhor usar o que você tem *expertise* do que se aventurar em algo ótimo que você não domina. A não ser que a vantagem seja brutal.

Por que estou dizendo isso? Para você entender minha situação e julgar se estou sendo tendencioso. As vantagens descritas existem mesmo e é difícil quem consiga listar vantagens genuinamente diferentes das apresentadas, elas podem ser detalhadas ou especificadas melhor, mas dificilmente encontrará algo diferente.

## Seu caso

Primeiro te digo para aproveitar a experiência. Tente manter a cabeça aberta e tente aprender uma forma de desenvolver que não está acostumado. Tentar mudar o rumo do que já foi decidido provavelmente só vai lhe trazer problemas e vai desperdiçar uma oportunidade de se desenvolver melhor.

Tente usar alguns dos itens que está lendo nas respostas aqui para tentar avaliar se tudo está correto no projeto. Mas perceba que cada projeto é diferente. Nem todas as vantagens e desvantagens serão encontradas em todos os projetos.

Seria terrível se você fosse o responsável pelo projeto e estivesse fazendo algo que não domina.

A maior pergunta que poderia fazer é: por que o projeto será centrado no DB? Se a decisão foi tomada com critérios adequados, se ela foi pensada, se foi levado em consideração todos os pontos que poderiam trazer vantagens ou desvantagens, provavelmente ele está no caminho certo.

O projeto é apenas um sistema interno? Qual é o *background* da equipe? Como será a evolução desta solução?

Boa prática é fazer o correto em cada situação, você descobrirá se é o caso neste projeto com o tempo.

## Conclusão

Basicamente se você preguntar para um programador (de verdade) ele vai dizer que é melhor colocar na aplicação. Se perguntar para o DBA (mesmo aquele que também programa), ele vai dizer que é melhor colocar no DB. Na maioria das vezes a decisão é tomada com base em experiências prévias ou ideias preconcebidas do que é o ideal. Você escolhe com quais problemas você quer lidar. Pode parecer que isso é ruim, mas não necessariamente. Surpreendentemente as pessoas decidem sem sequer saber porque.

Bom senso e experiência sempre contam mais que qualquer recomendação genérica. O problema é que cada um tem seu próprio bom senso e a experiência é influenciada por diversos fatores.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "Bom senso e experiência sempre contam mais que qualquer recomendação genérica. O problema é que cada um tem seu próprio bom senso e a experiência é influenciada por diversos fatores." Gostei dessa conclusão +1

Comment: No caso da lógica ser implementada no banco de dados, é possível implementar regras de acesso a informação, ou seja, determinar o que o utilizador pode ou não ver? Se sim, seria uma boa prática, uma vez que o propósito de um banco de dados é armazenar informação?

Comment: @FilipeMoraes é possível sim, e normalmente isto é feito.

Comment: O que seriam "regras de dados" e como se diferenciam das regras de negócio?