# Stored Proc X Entity - É uma boa decisão?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Em dias de Entity Framework, fazer um projeto MVC utilizando Stored Procedure é um bom caminho? Sempre ouvi isso: Se opta pelo EF não faz sentido utilizar SP, mas já ouvi pessoas dizerem que não necessariamente isso é uma verdade absoluta. Então vem a pergunta: SP X EF dá para usar os dois mundos ou não? Não é uma pergunta ampla e nem recebe muitas opiniões. A resposta seria deve-se usar os dois ou não em uma arquitetura MVC.

Comment: Depende de como você pense em utilizar a StoredProcedure. Não, não é uma boa prática, visto que você "mata" o LINQ e o EF. De fato, ao optar por não utilizar EF, uma boa opção é utilizar ADO.NET.

Comment: A pergunta não foi essa e sim, se há possibilidade de trabalhar com os dois e MVC, juntos. Quanto ao que você falou e agradeço, é como eu postei. Hoje eu tenho usado muito Ado.Net e de uma forma que um amigo que ensinou que tem sido bem legal, mas apenas quando eu uso WebForms. Com MVC tenho utilizado EF, mas como tenho um projeto em WebForms q gostaria que migrasse para MVC, então me veio a pergunta inicial, já que tudo está em SP. Daria menos trampo a migração, rs.

Comment: O que você quer saber exatamente? Você quer saber se dá para usar os dois junto com MVC?? Sim, dá... vai de acordo com as necessidades do projeto. Mas eu não considero uma boa prática não...dá para fazer tudo pelo EF e LINQ...use-os.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Em dias de Entity Framework, fazer um projeto MVC utilizando *Stored Procedure* é um bom caminho?

Não.

O intuito do Entity Framework para o desenvolvimento é economizar esforço de programação ao modelar o banco de dados como um alfaiate, ajustando-o perfeitamente ao código da aplicação, com as melhores práticas possíveis de normalização do banco de dados. Com isso, espera-se que as consultas também sejam otimizadas por seguirem um padrão natural de design de banco.

Colocando *Stored Procedures*, você estaria desperdiçando todo este trabalho que o *Framework* faz por você. A não ser que seja **muito** necessário ter uma atenção especial quanto à segurança, **depois de pronto**, pode ser interessante fazer o sistema realizar o acesso por *Stored Procedures*. [Explico tudo isso nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15739/regras-de-neg%C3%B3cio-no-banco-de-dados-quais-as-vantagens-e-desvantagens/15744#15744).

Comment: sem exceções? mesmo em consultas lentas, finalidade de tunning?

Comment: Na versão 6 isso foi bem melhorado. *Tuning* pode ser feito com a adição de alguns índices, não por *Stored Procedures*.