# Sql Server Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, orm, stored-procedures

Estou iniciando o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação, basicamente é um controle gerencial de empresas. A aplicação emitirá NFC-e, NFe, controlará estoque, financeiro e etc, o banco de dados será hospedado no Azure. Comecei modelando o banco de dados e criando stored procedures para manter os dados no banco, porem reparei que vou ter que criar uma quantidade enorme de stored procedures devido ao fato do banco conter muitos objetos. Estou cuidando para não inserir nada da camada de negócios nas stored procedures.

Como tenho pouca experiência estou confuso, pois alguns dizem que stored procedure é uma má pratica e só deve ser usada em questões onde se precisa de performance, exemplo [aqui](https://blog.codinghorror.com/who-needs-stored-procedures-anyways/). Outros dizem que vale a pena usar, exemplo [aqui](http://rob.conery.io/2015/02/21/its-time-to-get-over-that-stored-procedure-aversion-you-have/).

Na opinião dos mais experientes, qual o melhor caminho, usar um ORM ou criar todas as stored procedures que for necessário? É um problema um banco de dados ter um número grande de stored procedures ? [Nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135701/can-you-have-too-many-stored-procedures) tem um que diz ter 200 ou mais em um sistema comercial.

Comment: Sinalizei sua pergunta como baseada em opiniões. Isso depende. Não dá pra afirmar se melhor ou pior, boa ou má prática usar procedures. Já fiz sistemas repleto delas bem como com ORM.

Comment: @Murilo, também acho o mesmo.

Comment: Pode ler isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15739/101. Essa resposta diz que uma SP é muito: http://stackoverflow.com/a/135954/221800

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se a resposta for de um DBA, claro que ele vai dizer que não há problema algum e que deve ser criado procs no banco, se for um desenvolvedor que trabalha com um ORM, claro que ele vai falar para você usar seus métodos na aplicação para fazer seus CRUD.

A questão aqui é; você pode usar um ORM, sua aplicação vai suportar ele sem perda de performance?

Você trabalha com o banco de dados e aplicação ao mesmo tempo, ou tem um DBA que cuida do seu banco?

Isso tudo pode influencia na sua decisão.

Há varias razões para usar as [Stores procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190782.aspx), veja o trecho abaixo retirado [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739230/entity-framework-vs-stored-procedures-performance-measure).

Mas para ser honesto, um procedimento armazenado com mapeamento manual será sempre mais rápido no desempenho. Mas pergunte a si mesmo, o quão importante é o desempenho? Na maioria dos projetos, o tempo de desenvolvimento é muito mais importante do que o desempenho. O que foi mais difícil desenvolver? A consulta crua com a análise ou a consulta Entity Framework?

ORMs não são projetados porque eles executam muito melhor do que uma abordagem escrita mão. Nós usá-los porque o desenvolvimento é muito mais fácil!

Se você escrever a sua aplicação com o Entity Framework e ocultar todas as suas consultas por trás de um padrão de repositório você pode desenvolver bem rápido e, em seguida, quando o desempenho se torna um problema, medir o seu aplicativo para detectar o gargalo. Então, talvez algumas de suas consultas precisam otimização e pode ser movido para procedimentos armazenados e mapeamento manual.