# Melhor abordagem é filtrar dados no banco de dados ou na aplicação?

Tags: java, sql, banco-de-dados, desempenho, group-by

Suponha que temos uma tabela `'Vendas'` com as seguintes colunas `'estado', 'cidade', 'vendedor', 'valor'`.

`'estado'` e a `'cidade'` seria onde a venda foi realizada e `'vendedor'` seria o que fez essa venda. `'valor'` seria o valor da venda.

Qual a melhor, mais barata, mais inteligente abordagem para acumular esses valores por `'estado'` ou `'cidade'` ou `'vendedor'`?

**Fazer 3 selects:**

```
sql = "SELECT estado, sum(valor) 
       FROM vendas
       GROUP BY estado";

sql = "SELECT cidade, sum(valor) 
       FROM vendas
       GROUP BY cidade";

sql = "SELECT vendedor, sum(valor) 
       FROM vendas
       GROUP BY vendedor";
```

ou

**Fazer 1 select só e fazer os cálculos com a linguagem de programação**

`sql = "SELECT * FROM vendas";`

Deixar a cargo na linguagem de programação (no caso eu trabalho com Java) fazer esses cálculos, sendo que o trabalho braçal do programador seria mais pesado?

Comment: Se você pensar que a tabela vendas pode conter milhões de registros, fica claro que fazer os 3 selects é mais "barato".

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, era como eu imaginava.
Agora! Por favor. Mudei um pouco o cenário e fiz um comentário na resposta abaixo. Se possível, poderia comentar lá também?

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago: SEMPRE que possível filtre no banco de dados. Geralmente o sgbd gera plano de execução otimizado para filtrar, principalmente se houver índice que atenda à consulta. // Além disso, diminui o tráfego na rede. //

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago: Em alguns gerenciadores de banco de dados é possível fazer as 3 consultas em uma única leitura dos dados, usando GROUPING SETS. . O resultado retorna como um único conjunto de dados.

Comment: desculpa mas não entendi, é uma pergunta com resposta "pré-definida" e escolhida, apenas para dar a recompensa?

Comment: @AugustoVasques não faz sentido abrir uma recompensa para isso ao ver... o objetivo de uma recompensa é incentivar uma melhor resposta, por isso se ganha reputação extra... abrir um bounty e escrever "olha não é pra pariticpar pq esse bouty é pra resposta de fulano" não me parece fazer sentido do ponto de vista do bounty. Se vc quer dar recompensa pra alguém, deixe lá e escolha a resposta da pessoa (na verdade já estava escolhida), mas deixar o texto assim não parece certo "com a comunidade do SO". Um pergunta é um pergunta, qualquer um pode responder, não é um site privado

Comment: @AugustoVasques se colocar o mouse em cima do ícone que identifica uma resposta como resposta aceita, verá que eu aceitei a resposta em julho de 2017. Essa característica é do StackOverflow, mesmo uma pergunta já com resposta aceita é passível de receber mais respostas.

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago Não é sobre sua aceitação, estamos discutindo a recompensa. Fique tranquilo.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Deixe o banco de dados trabalhar por você.

Não que isso seja uma verdade absoluta. Mas trazer um monte de dados para a aplicação filtrar quase sempre é um erro. Digo quase porque sempre pode ter um cenário que eu não sei que pode ser útil ou a única forma viável. Mas consigo lembrar de um assim de cabeça.

Trazer dados demais tem custo para o banco de dados, para a infraestrutura e para a aplicação, sem falar que terá um código a mais para lidar.

Esse caso claramente é melhor usar o SQL completo e trazer só o que precisa. Veja se pode fazer as três consultas em um *query* só. Provavelmente não pode, porque as tecnologias mais usadas dificultam isso, mas depende um pouco de como está tudo organizado.

Pode ter algum caso muito específico e esquisito que seria melhor trazer tudo, mesmo assim seria pouco ganho e acho algo tão fora da curva que duvido que aconteceria de verdade.

Claro que precisa arquitetar a aplicação para trabalhar bem, precisa ver se o banco de dados está devidamente configurado para suportar esse *query* adequadamente.

Há controvérsias de qual é o limite que deve passar para o banco de dados. Muitos problemas de escalabilidade ocorrem porque o desenvolvedor sobrecarrega o banco de dados com coisas que ficariam melhores na aplicação. Sempre haverá a [discussão sobre o uso de Stored Procedures ou não](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15739/101).

Eu digo e repito, **muitas das técnicas e ferramentas que existem hoje foram criadas para resolver um problema criado por outra técnica que era desnecessária ou pior do que a simples**. Frequentemente as pessoas ignoram a [Navalha de Occam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor). Claro que sempre haverá o argumento que o mais complexo está fazendo algo a mais. Há casos que é verdade, mas há casos que é só complicação por não avaliar o todo, ou por gostar daquilo, ou só saber fazer de um jeito.

A parte "boa" é que criou-se uma indústria enorme por causa de tanto problema novo. Parecemos hamsters na rodinha.

[image: Hamster na rodinha]

Relacionado: [Por que usar "SELECT * FROM tabela" é ruim?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21583/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Era como eu imaginava.

Comment: Mudando um pouco o cenário.
Se eu também necessitar fazer um `"SELECT * FROM vendas"` porque irei alimentar uma tabela com esses registros e também gerar três gráficos alimentados por aqueles outros 3 selects que eu já mencionei.
Neste caso, ainda é melhor deixar a cargo do SQL?

Comment: Aí já acho que pode começar compensar trazer isto e depois gerar as outras na aplicação. Mas tem, uma coisa. Se for pequeno, fará pouco diferença, se for grande talvez tenha problema em trazer tudo. Precisaria ver se compensa o esforço de um código extra pra manipular isso. Mas precisa saber fazer, pelo fato de não ter um índice a seu serviço pode fazer esse filtro ficar bem mais lento que pedir de novo para o banco de dados. É o que eu falei no começo da pergunta, se o cenário mudar um pouco já não dá para responder tão claramente. A regra básica é fazer todos cenários e medir.

Comment: O que seria 'pequeno' pra ti? Hoje, o maior select desse cenário onde estou trabalhando está trazendo no máximo 500 registros.

Comment: Não dá pra falar em números, tem que medir.

Answer (score -4):

Acho que usar tanto o SELECT * FROM vendas quanto os 3 SELECT's bem estranho, talvez seria melhor fazer uma tabela que organize pelo menos uma coluna, como o nome do vendedor, por exemplo. Aí ficaria assim:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM vendas
       GROUP BY vendedor";
```

o "vendedor" ali em cima pode ser substituído por cidade ou estado

Comment: Note um agregado na consulta `sum(valor)`. Ciente disso veja que a pergunta é sobre se é mais vantajoso consultar todos os dados e então os somar dentro da linguagem de programação ou então somar dentro do banco de dados e da linguagem consultar apenas os resultados.

Answer (score -5):

Cada caso é um caso.

Acredito que esteja falando que, na interface, o usuário poderá selecionar a visualização de um relatório de vendas, com opção por cidade, estado ou vendedor.

O exemplo passado usa o SQL ANSI, que é executado em qual quer banco de dados. Não faz sentido usar a linguagem de programação (java) com um laço para fazer a soma. Você pode utilizar o hibernate para abstrair o SQL, ou não.

Uma solução e usar uma estrutura de seleção (if), e de acordo com a opção selecionada na interface executa o SQL correspondente, apresentando a lista conforme a opção escolhida.

Comment: Me parece que um banco bem projetado e por alguém experiente sempre vai levar para o lado de resolver no proprio banco, somente (ou geralmente) ao contrário, quando **não** é bem feito que vai ser o caso de usar *"cada caso como um caso"*, então digamos que para **gambiarras** assim em bancos do qual você **não** tem "controle" ou é **legado** e geralmente **mal feito**, sua resposta seria válida, agora se formos falar do que esta bem feito, planejado e por pessoas experientes (de ambos lados, quem projetou o banco e quem vai usa-lo) então isso de "caso a caso" seria errado.