# Especialização e generalização em banco de dados e desenvolvimento da aplicação

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, modelo-relacional, entidade-relacionamento

Tenho uma tabela `Livros` e sei que a especialização/generalização de livros são `Livros de Ficção`, `Livros de Drama` e `Livros de Suspense`, por exemplo.

Porem, no modelo lógico, eu não sei se eu crio uma tabela `Livros` com relacionamento *1:N* `Tipos de livros` com cada tipo cadastrado ou se crio uma tabela para cada especialização (`livro_drama`, `livro_ficção`)!

Sei que seria pouco viável criar uma tabela para cada `Tipo`, pois se eu precisasse de novos tipos de livros eu teria que criar sempre uma nova tabela. Mas se eu utilizar a outra forma, cada tipo de livro cadastrado teria suas regras de negocio especifica, mesmo cadastrando cada tipo, eu teria de programar as regras associadas.

Algo esta me incomodando em ambas as soluções! Como resolvo esse impasse?

Comment: Eu vejo assim: uma tabela para livros, e uma só contendo gêneros (suspense, drama, ficção científica, etc). Aí uma tabela associativa guardando a informação de que um livro pode ter um ou mais gêneros.

Comment: @Piovezan Exatamente isso que vi de inicio, mas com umas analises mais apuradas vi o seguinte caso: e se por exemplo os livros de suspense necessita-se de alguma regra especifica na aplicação, sendo ele um gênero? E os novos gêneros que fosse acrescentados ao sistema, eu constantemente teria que ficar remodelando o sistema com "possíveis" regras na aplicação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe algum motivo para ter uma especialização? Se tiver, tem algum motivo para ter uma generalização? Pode parecer óbvio, mas uma das duas parecem estar erradas em modelagem relacional. Se está falando em especialização não tem porque falar de relação, são conceitos excludentes.

Não faça algo sem motivo. Pergunte-se qual o motivo de usar algo? Que problema isto está resolvendo? E quais estão sendo causados?

Você diz que que cada tipo de livro tem regras de negócio específicas. É mesmo? tem certeza? Vamos dizer que sim, e por que as regras de negócio estão no banco de dados? Vamos dizer que queira fazer assim, o que a pergunta já mostra que isto não é uma boa ideia, que solução vê a não ser separar cada tipo em uma tabela? Se o dado se comporta diferente precisa estar em tabela diferente. Eu só não faria assim, dentro da minha visão, pode ser que precise mesmo de algo fora do normal.

Uma solução é ter uma tabela só e algumas ações que dependem do tipo serem feitas de forma condicional.

Não tem impasse algum. Eu não vejo nada de especialização ou relacionamento aí, portanto não há dicotomia. Só tem regras de negócio diferentes que são programadas na aplicação. Ou no banco de dados se preferir assim. Mas não tem porque criar uma tabela nova se a estrutura é a mesma. Banco de dados não é aplicação, embora alguns achem que é.

Veja [vantagens e desvantagens de por a regra de negócio no banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15746/101).

Comment: É exatamente esta duvida que estou passando por não ter uma boa analise inicial da aplicação. Não só por culpa minha, mas por que me passa tais requisitos, talvez até por não conhecer certas partes do processo me obrigando a ter que advinha certo pontos e evitar o máximo de problemas de manutenção futura. Então ao seu ver, seria tipo: somente a tabela "Livros" com os tipos "enums" e com regras na aplicação ou somente a tabela "gêneros"? Entendi seu ponto de vista.

Answer (score -4):

Eu tava pensando que suas especializações para livros fossem, por exemplo:

- Livros digitais
- Audiobooks
- Livros impressos

nos quais a natureza da experiência da leitura fosse diferente, em cada caso. Daí faria sentido uma especialização.

No mais, quanto ao critério de usar várias ou uma tabela, vai de acordo com a sua vontade, ou de acordo com a vontade do arquiteto de dados, basicamente.

Comment: Gostei dessa visão, realmente faz sentido. Me reforça cada vez mais que o ideal seria "gêneros dos livros" mas se eu tivesse que colocar uma regra neste tipo, por exemplo "Suspense" que alguma coisa seria diferente aqui. Eu faria só uma consulta do gênero "suspense" e programaria estas regra? mas e se por algum motivo o campo for deletado, a regra na aplicação ainda estaria lá. Sempre teria essa preocupação entre a aplicação e o banco. Tem alguma maneira de controlar melhor isso. Controle de versão não gerencia o banco de dados.

Comment: Em bibliotecas, normalmente se usa um código denominado CDD, https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/T%C3%B3pico:Wikilivros_Discuss%C3%A3o:Biblioteca/Classifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_e_categoriza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_dos_livros/resposta_(10) para classificar o assunto do livro, por isso, especializar o livro de acordo com o seu gênero seria supercomplicar o esquema de banco, eu acho!

Comment: Aqui: https://processotecnicoucs.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/classificacao-de-obras-literarias-ii/ também tem uma lista de classificação de gêneros literários por CDD/CDU.