# Manipulação de dados na programação ou no banco

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Supondo que eu necessite fazer a manipulação de um dado exemplo eu recebo o peso e a altura de um usuário. Eu quero calcular o IMC dela para inserir no banco de dados.
Esse calculo de IMC deve ser feito em uma função no código, ou através de uma trigger no S.G.B.D

O meu chefe que é gerente de Gestão da Informação me disse que esse tipo de verificação é feito no B.D

Mas o professor disse que o correto é fazer o calculo no código e só enviar o dado já pronto pro banco

Comment: entendo que já deveria guardar a informação já processada.

Comment: Eu entendo que a mesma coisa que o Doan. A regra de negócio deve estar no código e não no banco de dados que apenas fica a cargo de manter e recolher as informações e garantir que nenhuma informação seja inserida incorreta, caso o código faça inserções incorretas.

Comment: Leia essa questão, vai te ajudar bastante: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15739/regras-de-neg%C3%B3cio-no-banco-de-dados-quais-as-vantagens-e-desvantagens

Comment: Para calcular o IMC, em minha opinião usar _trigger_ seria um absurdo. É mais simples utilizar uma coluna calculada no banco de dados, que recalcule o IMC automaticamente a cada alteração nos valores da fórmula. Ou então fazer o cálculo no código e armazenar no banco de dados.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Regras de Negócio no Banco de Dados - quais as vantagens e desvantagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15739/regras-de-neg%c3%b3cio-no-banco-de-dados-quais-as-vantagens-e-desvantagens)

Answer (score 1):

O que é certo ou errado sempre depende muito de pontos de vistas.

O que eu recomendo é que os dados sejam armazenados no banco de dados, e toda a regra de negócio seja feita em código.

Pois se precisar um dia mudar de banco de dados, não terá que alterar a regra de negócio.