# É mais sensato usar validações no lado do cliente em Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

De acordo com sua a própria experiência é melhor usar validações no *client-side*? Porque se formos analisar, o Rails, nas validações padrão, envia a requisição, faz a validação e depois retorna os erros. Esse processo, apesar de não ser demorado (em desenvolvimento local), pela lógica, não consome mais processamento do servidor? Não seria melhor em termos de performance, fazer as validações diretamente no *client-side* com JavaScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não deixe de fazer a validação no servidor. Se houver um bug na sua aplicação (ou ataques mal intencionados) e entrar dados inconsistentes na base, será muito difícil para corrigir.

Eu recomendo que você faça validação em pelo menos 2 lugares:

- Banco de dados, através de *constraints* (*not null*, *foreign keys* e *unique indexes*)
- Aplicação (camada de modelo do Rails)

Colocar validação no JavaScript é mais uma conveniência para o usuário (ele não precisa enviar o formulário para ver que algum campo está incorreto), isso fica a teu critério. Mas o que vai garantir a segurança mesmo são as duas abordagens acima.

Eu sempre sugiro colocar a segurança e confiabilidade acima do desempenho. Além do mais, não creio que a diferença de desempenho seja considerável nesse caso.

---

Veja essas duas perguntas relacionadas:

- *[É realmente necessário definir constraints no banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15702/e-realmente-necessario-definir-constraints-no-banco-de-dados)*
- *[Regras de Negócio no Banco de Dados - quais as vantagens e desvantagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15739/regras-de-negocio-no-banco-de-dados-quais-as-vantagens-e-desvantagens?lq=1)*

**Dica**:

Tu pode usar a gem *[foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner)* para ter integração de *foreign keys* com o versionamento de banco do Rails (*migration*).

Lembre que há métodos que **não** acionam as validações do Rails:

```
- decrement!
- decrement_counter
- increment!
- increment_counter
- toggle!
- touch
- update_all
- update_attribute
- update_column
- update_columns
- update_counters
```

Tu também pode explicitamente pular a validação dessa forma:

```
- save(validate: false)
```

Fonte: *[Guia oficial do Rails sobre validações](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#skipping-validations)*

Answer (score 6):

O ideal é que você faça as validações no cliente *E* no servidor.

Validar do lado do cliente é legal justamente pelos motivos que você falou (economizar banda, menor tempo de resposta, UX mais legal, etc), mas também é necessário validar o servidor, mesmo que o seu cliente normalmente acabe não precisando fazer as requisições.

O motivo é a segurança, já que é bastante simples que alguém mal-intencionado possa fazer requisições HTTP maliciosas diretamente para o seu servidor, ignorando a "proteção" do cliente.

Answer (score 5):

Faça uma validação nos 2 lados.

Se a validação do cliente falhar por algum motivo, ainda terá no servidor ela para revalidar e assegurar que não tenha problemas.

Caso a primeira validação passe, em tese, não haveria porque revalidar depois, mas isso evita algumas dores de cabeça também.

Melhor **pecar** por excesso em validação do que não validar.