# Campos extras não salvam com Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Sou novo em rails e estou tentando implementar o Devise com alguns campos extras.
Ele está salvando o email e password corretamente, mas os meus campos `first_name` e `last_name`não estão sendo salvos. Está `nil`

Essa é minha view do registration.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :first_name %></div>

 <div><%= f.label :last_name %><br />
 <%= f.text_field :last_name %></div>

<div><%= f.label :profile_name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :profile_name %></div>

 <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

 <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

 <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

E esse é meu model User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

Não está aprensentando nenhum erro na hora de salvar o usuário

Comment: É o Rails 3 ou Rails 4?

Comment: desculpe, rails 4.1.1

Comment: Já tem as colunas first_name e last_name no banco?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `Devise` utiliza [strong parameters](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters), ou seja, ele tem que cuidar quando você deseja adicionar novos campos ao `sign_up` e `sign_in`. No caso, explicitarei como deve ser feito para o registro (`sign_up`).

### Caso você não tenha os campos adicionais no banco de dados

Nesse caso, você, primeiramente, deverá inseri-los no tabela `Users` (ou na tabela análoga, caso você não tenha usado `user` como padrão). Para isso é necessário criar um `migrate` vazio, da seguinte forma:

```
rails generate migration AddFieldsToUsers
```

Isso gerará uma `migration` vazia com o nome `AddFieldToUsers`, nela você deverá adicionar ao método `change` **todos** os campos que você deseja que sejam registrados (nesse caso first_name e last_name). O resultado deverá ser o seguinte:

```rb
class AddFieldsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :first_name, :string
    add_column :users, :last_name, :string
  end
end
```

Então, deve-se executar o seguinte comando:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Isso deverá gerar os campos na tabela `Users`.

### Adicionando campos à ação de registro

Como citado, deverá ser utilizado o `strong parameters`. Para isso, basta adicioná-los ao seu controlador da aplicação. Isso gerará um resultado semelhante ao seguinte:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :last_name
  end
end
```

Isso deverá resolver os seus problemas.

Comment: Quando tiver muitos elementos é possivel passar um block 

 devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
     u.permit(:first_name, :last_name)
end

Answer (score 1):

Esse comportamento é esperado. O Devise exige que você informe colunas adicionais na aplicação (além de adicionar as colunas no banco, é claro).

Pra isso faça assim no `aplication_controller.rb`:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :last_name
  end
end
```

Confira: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Também te recomendo [adicionar *constraints* NOT NULL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15702/e-realmente-necessario-definir-constraints-no-banco-de-dados) nessas duas colunas.