# É recomendável testar validações de modelo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mvc, testes, testes-de-unidade, tdd

Minha experiência é com Ruby on Rails, mas creio que minha pergunta servirá para outros casos.

O ORM ActiveRecord (do Rails) permite validar em campos coisas como:

- Presença
- Unicidade
- Tamanho (de uma *string*)
- [etc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validation-helpers)

Estou em dúvida se deveria criar testes para conferir se essas validações estão funcionando. Às vezes acho que não faz muito sentido, principalmente a *presença* de um campo, pois isso eu já posso definir via banco através de uma *constraint* `NOT NULL`, portanto é redundante.

Além do mais, parece que testar validações do modelo dá mais trabalho que testar os controladores. E quando eu testo um controlador, de certa forma estou testando o modelo também, pois o controlador manipula o modelo.

É recomendável ou não criar testes para as validações de modelo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minha resposta é:

Depende,
se você ou sua equipe usa shoulda-matchers, como citado em outra resposta, testar 
validações se torna algo trivial, então teste.

Eu porém, acredito que o shoulda-matchers é uma dependência desnecessária e você não precisa testar nem validações muito simples (como validates_presence_of) nem associações.
Esse tipo de código vem direto do Rails e o único jeito de você cometer um erro nele seria digitando errado o nome do campo, que acredito ser algo fácil de se observar.

Mas imagine um caso em que a validação depende de uma expressão regular razoavelmente complexa, por exemplo para validar um número telefônico. Nesse caso, como o código não é tão trivial seria interessante ter testes de caso para telefones mais comuns válidos e inválidos e inclusive alguns casos excepcionais para garantir.

Essa abordagem de teste também vale para escopos: se está criando um escopo bem simples, com uma query trivial, não escreva o teste. Porém, se o escopo envolve regras complexas e custom SQL, então vale a pena testá-lo.

Assista a palestra do Alexandre Freire, 'o que não testar' para entender melhor:
http://www.infoq.com/br/presentations/o-que-nao-testar

Muitas pessoas vão dizer que você deve testar tudo e deve ter 100% de cobertura. Eu diria que o certo é testar aquilo que é importante para sua aplicação: a lógica de negócio dela e coisas que não foram testadas pelo desenvolver do framework.
Ou seja, deve se testar o máximo de lógica que não depende do framework. E a garantia de que o framework funciona deve estar nos teste de alto nível (de integração), que não testarão todo o código mas servirão como um teste de sanidade para garantir que as partes funcionam em conjunto e que o framework faz seu papel.

Answer (score 3):

Em relação à situação de criar testes para as validações, a minha resposta é Não. Isto porque, provavelmente, já estará a usar uma framework que já tem testes e garante que essas validações funcionam.

Assim sendo, evita estar a testar o que já foi testado.

Quanto à necessidade de definir ou não as validações, eu diria que o melhor é definir. É verdade, podem (e devem) ser criados constraints na própria BD. A diferença é que se chegar à base de dados sem um valor obrigatório (por exemplo), a query vai dar erro. Enquanto que se tiver as validações no modelo, é possível informar o utilizador de forma mais agradável.

É claro que os erros "graceful" também dependem do próprio ORM / Framework com que está a trabalhar.

Comment: Sim, definir validações é fundamental, senão teríamos que usar `try/catch` para tratar erros. Quanto a testar as validações, talvez seja mais necessário se você não quiser definir *contraints* no banco.

Comment: Validar o modelo também ajuda na questão de desempenho, pois evita sobrecarregar a rede e o servidor de banco de dados com algo que poderia ter sido verificado antes.

Comment: @utluiz Não acho que o ganho de desempenho seria perceptível na maioria dos casos (mas isso é mais um chute meu do que experiência). Além do mais, se o sistema for *web*, a validação vai ser feita no servidor de qualquer jeito. E [há motivos importantes para criar *constraints* no banco](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15702/7261).

Comment: @Andrey Você está considerando casos simples, como cadastros. Mesmo assim, o *overhead* de abrir conexão e transferir dados entre o processo da aplicação e o processo do banco de dados pode ser grande se forem realizadas várias operações consecutivas. Se você estiver inserindo, por exemplo, 72 parcelas no banco de dados de uma operação de financiamento e a última tiver um problema, o tempo será bem perceptível, já que o sistema terá aberto uma transação e inserido dados em várias tabelas, criado vários *locks* e transferido os dados da operação e mais 72 parcelas.

Comment: Minha preocupação é que sempre somos otimistas demais sobre "isso não vai afetar tanto o desempenho". Eu também pensava assim, até que um dia tive que virar de cabeça para baixo um sistema usado em várias revendas porque ele estava dando *timeout*. Apenas com algumas otimizações "bestas" consegui diminuir o tempo em 90%, pois de pouco em pouco o "não perceptível" passava a ser praticamente insuportável.

Comment: Outro problema que pode ocorrer é se houver alta concorrência, isto é, muitos usuários. Deixar a validação para o banco significa também abrir uma conexão desnecessária em muitos casos. É claro que cada sistema é diferente, mas é bom pensar duas vezes antes de supor que não haverá problemas de concorrência, principalmente se o sistema for usado online. Entretanto, se for um sistema interno eu concordo com voc~e.

Answer (score 1):

Depende de como você está desenvolvendo.

Se você está fazendo design orientado por testes, ou seja Red-Green-Refactor faz sentido garantir que as validações existam no model.

Usando shoulda (https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda), você facilita bastante os testes.

Ex:

```
describe Post do
  it { should belong_to(:user) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:title) }
end
```

Comment: Não conhecida essa *gem*, vou estudá-la mais tarde. Parece bem mais simples do que criar os testes na mão.